# En Javascript a la hora de declarar un objeto con class constructor... ¿se le puede asignar mas de un producto a una misma categoría?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, instancias

En este código solo quería saber si a la hora de declarar un objeto bajo la nomenclatura de clases, es decir, un class constructor, le puedo asignar mas de un producto a una misma categoría o sea si le puedo asignar mas de un modelo a una misma marca para poder armar un catálogo de dichos productos. Por ejemplo:

```
const marca = ["VOLKSWAGEN", "BWM", "AUDI", "PORSCHE"]

const modelos= [];
modelos.push(new Autos(1, "Amarok Trendline", 20000,marca[0]))
modelos.push(new Autos(2, "M240i Coupé", 30000,marca[1]))
modelos.push(new Autos(3, "Clase C Coupé", 50000,marca[2]))
modelos.push(new Autos(4, "Q7 SportBack", 70000,marca[3]))
modelos.push(new Autos(5, "911 Carrera 4", 351000,marca[4]))
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda? Si el constructor de la Clase recibe una cadena como parámetro de *nombre de modelo*, entonces no puedes asignar más de un *nombre de modelo* a dicho objeto. Lo que si puedes tener es diferentes objetos que pertenezcan a la misma marca, pero son modelos diferentes, un objeto por modelo. Dicho esto, repito ¿Cuál es la duda?

Comment: No entendí... estás queriendo preguntar que si puedes asignar por ejemplo BMW a dos autos distintos? Si es así, la respuesta es SI... si no es eso lo que preguntas, entonces podrías aclararar mejor cual es la duda.